# How to mock all the classes that implement the same interface while using autowire for Set in spring?

Tags: java, spring, mocking, mockito, junit4

Having the following classes :

```
public class A {
     @Autowired
     private Set<IClient> clients;  
 }

public class B implements IClient { }

public class C implements IClient { }


@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Atest {
    @InjectMocks
    A a;

    @Mock
    IClient clients;
}
```

How I can use mocks for the `Set` of interfaces that will include both class `B` and `C`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use constructor injection insted of field injection, then create two mocks, put them in a set, and call your constructor with that set. For example:

```
public class Atest {
    private A a;

    @Mock
    private IClient mockAClient;

    @Mock
    private IClient mockBClient;

    @Before
    public void prepare() {
        a = new A(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(mockAClient, mockBClient));
    }

}
```